# Windows 10, down arrow skips a line every time

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have an issue where I reinstalled in windows 10 and now may down arrow key always skips a line every time. I have tried using 3 different keyboards, 2 wireless and one USB keyboard. I reinstalled windows 10 again and still the same issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which programs have you checked for this behavior in?

Comment: multiple .. Word, IE, Chrome, Kodi